# Haskell compare parts of input strings

Tags: haskell

How would I write out a code where the user inputs a string and is then part of the input is compared against a second input. For example; two numbers share the same 1-4 numbers so, 123456 and 123467 would have an output of they are same, but 123456 and 134567 would have an output of they are different.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html). There are bunch of useful functions. Your particular function may look like this:

```
import Data.List

shares4 :: String -> String -> Bool
shares4 s1 s2 =
    any (\s -> isSubsequenceOf s s2) -- we check if any of subsequences of first string are in the second
    $ filter (\s -> length s == 4) -- we take only those that are 4 chars long
    $ subsequences s2 -- returns all possible subsequences of a string
```

Comment: `subsequences` will return some non-contiguous character sequences. You probably want a combination of `tails` and `take 4` instead.